# Playing around with builtin functions

Tags: python

So I was playing around with `dir()` function. I ran a simple `dir(builtins)` function which gave me a list of defined names. What was unexpected is when I ran this just to fool around:

```
dir('\nbuiltins')
```

This gave a me a entirely different list of names. Can someone explain what is going on? :) thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) returns names of attributes of the given object.

`'\nbuiltins'` is a string literal. So you get attribute names of the string object.

Comment: I see, so any string literal I type in the `dir` function will give me the same list. Basically its returning me all of the attributes/methods I can perform on a string?

Comment: @bLunt, You're right. Likewise you will get same list for `dir([])`, `dir([1])`, `dir([1] + [2, 3, 4])`, .... ; which all return attribute names for `list`.